# Getting unknow columns from list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have my list contained other 119,554 lists in. All the lists have the same length of 334 lists. I needed to covert list into dataframe using `df2=pd.DataFrame(df)`. The result shows `(119554, 706)`

I don't know why there are additional columns added. It should be `(119554, 33)` if I'm not wrong.

Any suggestion? Thank!

Comment: How did you create the dataframe?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - emphasis on minimal (including some data).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following lists within another list:

```py
lst = [[1, 2, 3], 
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [10, 11, 12]]
```

You can see that the list contains *4 lists* having *length 3*. Lists do not have `shape` attribute.

You can convert this list into a pandas dataframe in the following way:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
|    |   0 |   1 |   2 |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
|  1 |   4 |   5 |   6 |
|  2 |   7 |   8 |   9 |
|  3 |  10 |  11 |  12 |
```

The shape of the dataframe is:

```py
print(df.shape)
```

```py
>> (4, 3)
```

Comment: It supposed to be like that but my dataframe having additional more columns with unknown (nan) values

Comment: Without seeing your list, and how you are making the dataframe, it's hard to know why that is happening. Post  how you are making your dataframe.